# Google Chrome Strange Tint

Tags: google-chrome, browser, tint

After installing the Elder Scrolls Online beta this past weekend, I noticed my Google Chrome browser had picked up a strange red-ish tint. Also, the drop down auto complete looked washed-out and unreadable. (see picture) I have Firefox open to the left to for comparison. I notice that the affected area includes the containing window, as well as the client area. I hadn't noticed this problem with any other program.

I've tried restarting my computer, re-installing Chrome, and playing around with the themes in Google Chrome--with no success.

[image: Firefox Vs. Problem with Google Chrome]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that stereo 3D anaglyph was (unbeknownst to me) activated in the Nvidia Control Panel. Games weren't showing up in stereo 3D, so I had no indication is was ever enabled. But the solution was as simple as disabling stereo 3D in the Nvidia Control Panel.

[image: Solution: Un-check Stereoscopic 3D]

Answer (score 4):

This link helped me:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/6ekwqHMLlh4

Basically:

1. In Chrome, in the address bar type: chrome://settings/
2. Scroll to the bottom of the page and uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available"

Hope it helps someone else.